# Cannot send data from the host to a docker container consistently

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tcp, docker-for-mac

I have an application listening on port 1234 for client connections inside docker container. I can connect to port 1234 on localhost but cannot send bytes.

The container is started using docker run -p 1234:1234 name.

```
public static void start() {
    try {
        if (isServerAvailable()) {
            LOGGER.info("The host is available");
            outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            String message = SampleMessageFactory.getMessage("PhilipsMessage1.txt");
            LOGGER.info("Sending Message:{}", message);
            // MLLP Wrapping
            outputStream.write(new byte[] { 0x0B });
            outputStream.write(message.getBytes(EncodingConstant.UTF8.getEncodingName()));
            outputStream.write(new byte[] { 0x1C });
            outputStream.write(new byte[] { 0x0D });
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}

public static boolean isServerAvailable() {
    boolean result = false;
    for (;;) {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("The Server is not accepting connections on port 1234");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: any exceptions errors? Are you running on linux /windows / windows + Virtural box?

Comment: No errors. I am running on docker for mac.

Comment: did your application work even once? or was this problem like this even in the first try?

Comment: it always works first try when I download a new image. it is working randomly. I can't get it to behave consistently.

Comment: Try  LOGGER.error("The Server is not accepting connections on port 1234",e);  so you will see more info. Consider mapping to diffrent port with higher number e.g. -p 401234:1234.

Comment: Isn't it possible that another instance of the application is also running in another container? `docker ps --all` . Also I am wondering if it helps if you completely remove the old ones that might still be bound?

Comment: @muratiakos no other instance is running.